# Unable to execute command on server using j2ssh

Tags: ssh, j2ssh

I connected to a unix server through ssh and tried to execute a "ls" command and obtain it's output. The code is like this

```
SessionChannelClient session = client.openSessionChannel();
       session.startShell();
       String cmd = "ls -l";
       session.executeCommand(cmd);           
       ChannelInputStream in = session.getInputStream();
       ChannelOutputStream out = session.getOutputStream();
       IOStreamConnector input = new IOStreamConnector(System.in, session.getOutputStream());
       IOStreamConnector output = new IOStreamConnector(session.getInputStream(), System.out);
```

After running I was not getting any output in log file. What I found is that the channel request is failing as shown

> 1019 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.connection.ConnectionProtocol  - Channel request succeeded
>   1020 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.session.SessionChannelClient  - Requesting command execution
>   1021 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.session.SessionChannelClient  - Command is ls -l
>   1021 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.connection.ConnectionProtocol  - Sending exec request for the session channel
>   1021 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon  - Sending SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_REQUEST
>   1021 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.connection.ConnectionProtocol  - Waiting for channel request reply
>   1032 [Transport protocol 1] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon  - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA
>   1033 [ssh-connection 1] DEBUG com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.Service  - Routing SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA
>   1033 [ssh-connection 1] DEBUG com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.Service  - Finished processing SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_EXTENDED_DATA
>   1075 [Transport protocol 1] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.transport.TransportProtocolCommon  - Received SSH_MSG_CHANNEL_FAILURE
>   1075 [main] INFO  com.sshtools.j2ssh.connection.ConnectionProtocol  - Channel request failed

Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startShell` **or** `executeCommand`, but not both.

`executeCommand` is only intended to invoke a particular shell of your choosing, e.g. /bin/bash. In most cases you can just use `startShell` to start the default shell.

This is all you need to execute the command you provided:

```
final String cmd = "ls -l" + '\n';       
session.startShell();
session.getOutputStream().write(cmd.getBytes());
```

Or, alternatively, using executeCommand:

```
final String cmd = "ls -l";    
session.executeCommand(String.format("sh -c \"%s\"", cmd));
```

You can hook up to the stdout & stderr `InputStream`s in the same manner to see the result of your command. Further, note that a `SessionChannelClient` can only process one command. You'll need to instantiate another one to send a second command.

I suggest you download the [J2SSH documentation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshtools/files/J2SSH-Tutorials/1.0.0/). Inside you'll find *j2ssh-getting-started.htm* which explains the basic operation of the API.